# Golang aztables Authorization failure with az login

Tags: azure, go, azure-table-storage

I'm trying to follow along the tutorial at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table/how-to-use-go?tabs=bash, and the credential I get from `azidentity.NewDefaultAzureCredential` is able to create a table, so it has sufficient roles for that, but when it calls `client.AddEntity` I'm getting a 403 error.

I used `az login` to log into my root level account, and it's got the Global Administrator role, and has enough privileges to add a table, but not enough privileges to add an entity. Is there something I need to configure differently on the table or the storage account?

```golang
    cred, err := azidentity.NewDefaultAzureCredential(nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    serviceURL := fmt.Sprintf("https://%s.table.core.windows.net/%s", accountname, tablename)
    client, err := aztables.NewClient(serviceURL, cred, nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    _, err := client.CreateTable(context.TODO(), nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
        myEntity := InventoryEntity{
        Entity: aztables.Entity{
            PartitionKey: "pk001",
            RowKey:       "rk001",
        },
        Price:       3.99,
        Inventory:   20,
        ProductName: "Markers",
        OnSale:      false,
    }

    marshalled, err := json.Marshal(myEntity)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    _, err = client.AddEntity(context.TODO(), marshalled, nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
```

The last line is the one that's failing, even though before that I'm able to connect and create the table. The same account is able to delete the table afterward as well.

Comment: Well, everything in the example works if I use the table name `mytable`, but I can't seem to use any other table name (`mytable1`, `mytablee`, etc.) - and of course, I have to skip the step at the beginning to `az storage table create` because that actually creates the table, which I would then have to delete before running the example.

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and got the below results:**

Initially, I tried with the same code and got a similar error:

> RESPONSE493: 493 Forbidden ERRORCODE: AuthorizationPermissionMismatch “odata.error"™:{ “code": “AuthorizationPermissionMismatch", i okcs-y-|1 “lang”: “en-US", “value”: "This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.\nRequestId:fb@70c8d-4902-@0e2-1bed-db23 97000000\nTime:2023-08-30T@6:44:4xxx" goroutine 1 [running]:

[image]

The above error occurs when your user may not have the necessary permissions to add an entity to a table.

You need to assign **`Storage table data contributor role`** to your user.

[image]

You can use the below code to create a table and add an entity using Golang.

**Code:**

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/azidentity"
    "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/data/aztables"
)

type InventoryEntity struct {
    aztables.Entity
    Price       float64 `json:"Price"`
    Inventory   int     `json:"Inventory"`
    ProductName string  `json:"ProductName"`
    OnSale      bool    `json:"OnSale"`
}

func main() {
    accountName := "venkat123"
    tableName := "table1"

    
    cred, err := azidentity.NewDefaultAzureCredential(nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    serviceURL := fmt.Sprintf("https://%s.table.core.windows.net/%s", accountName, tableName)
    client, err := aztables.NewClient(serviceURL, cred, nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Create the table
    _, err = client.CreateTable(context.Background(), nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Add an entity to the table
    myEntity := InventoryEntity{
        Entity: aztables.Entity{
            PartitionKey: "pk001",
            RowKey:       "rk001",
        },
        Price:       3.99,
        Inventory:   20,
        ProductName: "Markers",
        OnSale:      false,
    }

    marshalled, err := json.Marshal(myEntity)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    _, err = client.AddEntity(context.Background(), marshalled, nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

**Portal:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[Use the Azure Table client library for Go | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table/how-to-use-go?tabs=bash#create-a-table)